# canvas in foreignObject in defs/use not displayed

Tags: svg, html5-canvas

I want to use JavaScript to draw on an html5 canvas embedded in svg (in an html5 page). Drawing on "cvs" works just fine if done this way:

```
<svg id="fig" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1024px" height="1024px" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
  <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="512" height="512">
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <canvas id="cvs" width="512" height="512"></canvas>
    </body>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

but not if done with the canvas in  and referred to in a **use** tag. The drawing simply doesn't appear. Inspecting the element in Safari tells me that the the dimensions of the **use** element are NaN x NaN; Firebug says 0x0.

```
<svg id="fig" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1024px" height="1024px" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
  <defs>
    <foreignObject id="circles" x="0" y="0" width="512" height="512">
      <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <canvas id="cvs" width="512" height="512"></canvas>
      </body>
    </foreignObject>
  </defs>
  <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#circles"></use>
</svg>
```

Is this a bug? Expected behavior? Do I just not understand how to use foreignObject (highly likely)?

Comment: Try `<use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#circles"></use>`

Comment: @Duopixel Argh, editing error. The version I'm testing does have #circles instead of #cvs in the use tag. I'll try to edit my question to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't point to a foreignObject element directly, it says so in the [SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement)

‘svg’, ‘symbol’, ‘g’, graphics element or other ‘use’ only. So you could point to a `<g>` or `<svg>` element that had a `<foreignObject>` element as a child for instance.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your answer. In the original question, I mistakenly typed xlink:href="#cvs" (the canvas object in my foreignObject) instead of "#circles" (the foreignObject itself). Neither one works.
I've now tried wrapping my foreignObject in the defs in <g>, <svg>, or <symbol> tags, giving an id to that tag and giving xlink:href="#groupdefid" or whatever. Still no display. 
It's not a big deal for my current task, because there are other ways of accomplishing it, but it would be nice to know how to make this work.

Comment: Robert is suggesting to wrap the foreignObject in a `g` or `svg` and reference that.

Comment: @Duopixel Looks like our comments crossed. I just tried that; no luck.

Comment: Even if I just put the canvas in a foreignObject (no defs, first version above), Safari ignores transformations applied to it. (Firefox does the transformations properly.) Given that limitation, I can't use this approach anyway, so there's no urgency about finding a solution.

Comment: You should raise a bug on webkit then I guess.

Comment: @RobertLongson It turns out to be a problem with Safari, not WebKit. Chrome handles it properly. I've found several other svg issues that are fixed in the WebKit version Chrome uses, while Safari is lagging.